# Problem deploying my Angular 5 application into Heroku

Tags: angular, heroku, npm

I have been trying to deploy my Angular 5 application, into Heroku.
I already did this for other projects, but for this one, there might have some dependency problem and I can not do the same.

On my local machine, I can run `ng build` without any errors.

On the other hand, when Heroku is running this command (`ng build`), I receive the following error:

```
-----> Build
remote:        Detected both "build" and "heroku-postbuild" scripts
remote:        Running heroku-postbuild
remote:        
remote:        > remeli-web@0.0.2 heroku-postbuild /tmp/build_aa000f62bacba3344bfd7e2865e0bc78
remote:        > ng build
remote:        
remote: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:775
remote:     throw err;
remote:     ^
remote: 
remote: Error: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/core'
remote: Require stack:
remote: - /tmp/build_aa000f62bacba3344bfd7e2865e0bc78/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/src/tree/virtual.js
remote: - /tmp/build_aa000f62bacba3344bfd7e2865e0bc78/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/src/tree/filtered.js
remote: - /tmp/build_aa000f62bacba3344bfd7e2865e0bc78/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/src/tree/static.js
remote: - /tmp/build_aa000f62bacba3344bfd7e2865e0bc78/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/src/index.js
remote: - /tmp/build_aa000f62bacba3344bfd7e2865e0bc78/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/schematics.js
remote: - /tmp/build_aa000f62bacba3344bfd7e2865e0bc78/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/generate.js
remote: - /tmp/build_aa000f62bacba3344bfd7e2865e0bc78/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/cli/index.js
remote: - /tmp/build_aa000f62bacba3344bfd7e2865e0bc78/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
remote:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:772:15)
remote:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:677:27)
remote:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:830:19)
remote:     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:68:18)
remote:     at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_aa000f62bacba3344bfd7e2865e0bc78/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/src/tree/virtual.js:10:16)
remote:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:936:30)
remote:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:947:10)
remote:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:32)
remote:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:703:12)
remote:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:830:19) {
remote:   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
remote:   requireStack: [
remote:     '/tmp/build_aa000f62bacba3344bfd7e2865e0bc78/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/src/tree/virtual.js',
remote:     '/tmp/build_aa000f62bacba3344bfd7e2865e0bc78/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/src/tree/filtered.js',
remote:     '/tmp/build_aa000f62bacba3344bfd7e2865e0bc78/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/src/tree/static.js',
remote:     '/tmp/build_aa000f62bacba3344bfd7e2865e0bc78/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/src/index.js',
remote:     '/tmp/build_aa000f62bacba3344bfd7e2865e0bc78/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/schematics.js',
remote:     '/tmp/build_aa000f62bacba3344bfd7e2865e0bc78/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/generate.js',
remote:     '/tmp/build_aa000f62bacba3344bfd7e2865e0bc78/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/cli/index.js',
remote:     '/tmp/build_aa000f62bacba3344bfd7e2865e0bc78/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng'
remote:   ]
remote: }
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 1
remote: npm ERR! remeli-web@0.0.2 heroku-postbuild: `ng build`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote: npm ERR! 
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the remeli-web@0.0.2 heroku-postbuild script.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote: 
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.jo13D/_logs/2020-04-10T21_07_21_257Z-debug.log
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:        
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:        
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:        
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected
```

My **package.json** is the  following:

```
{
  "name": "remeli-web",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check --port 4242 -w --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "build": "ng build --env prod --prod --aot",
    "build-homolog": "ng build --env homolog --prod --aot",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "heroku-postbuild": "ng build"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.1.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.3.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.9",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.6.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.6.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0",
    "@ngx-share/core": "^5.3.1",
    "@types/promise.prototype.finally": "^2.0.2",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.23.3",
    "angular2-notifications": "^1.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta",
    "compass-mixins": "^0.12.10",
    "core-js": "^2.5.3",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "install": "^0.10.2",
    "moment": "^2.19.4",
    "ng2-dnd": "^5.0.2",
    "ng2-img-cropper": "^0.9.0",
    "ng2-trim-directive": "^2.1.0",
    "ng2-truncate": "^1.3.11",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.0",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^0.8.2",
    "ngx-slick": "^0.1.3",
    "npm": "^5.6.0",
    "pretty-checkbox": "^3.0.3",
    "promise.prototype.finally": "^3.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.5",
    "ts-md5": "^1.2.2",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.2",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.0.58",
    "codelyzer": "~4.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "protractor": "~5.2.1",
    "ts-node": "~4.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.8.0",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.9.0",
    "npm": "6.13.0"
  }
}
```

I also tried to add the dependency (even though I don't need to add the dependency to build my project locally).

I run `npm install @angular-devkit/core` and get `"@angular-devkit/core": "^9.1.1"`

I push again to heroku, and the error changes to:

```
remote:        > ng build
remote:        
remote:        
remote:        @angular/compiler-cli@5.2.11 requires typescript@'>=2.4.2 <2.5.0' but 2.9.2 was found instead.
remote:        Using this version can result in undefined behaviour and difficult to debug problems.
remote:        
remote:        Please run the following command to install a compatible version of TypeScript.
remote:        
remote:            npm install typescript@'>=2.4.2 <2.5.0'
remote:        
remote:        To disable this warning run "ng set warnings.typescriptMismatch=false".
remote:        
remote:        Date: 2020-04-10T21:19:58.382Z
remote:        Hash: 668a7a095131daade445
remote:        Time: 27626ms
remote:        chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 5.83 kB [entry] [rendered]
remote:        chunk {main} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 889 kB [initial] [rendered]
remote:        chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 399 kB [initial] [rendered]
remote:        chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 277 kB [initial] [rendered]
remote:        chunk {vendor} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map (vendor) 9.45 MB [initial] [rendered]
remote: 
remote: ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"ident":"postcss","sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false,"precision":8,"includePaths":[]}!./src/assets/sass/app.scss
remote: Module build failed: 
remote:   @return mix($color-base, $color, $level * $theme-color-interval);
remote:          ^
remote:       Argument `$color-2` of `mix($color-1, $color-2, $weight: 50%)` must be a color
remote:       in /tmp/build_b1b8a012dd41e35e651d945fbbda4881/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_functions.scss (line 96, column 11)
remote: Error: 
remote:   @return mix($color-base, $color, $level * $theme-color-interval);
remote:          ^
remote:       Argument `$color-2` of `mix($color-1, $color-2, $weight: 50%)` must be a color
remote:       in /tmp/build_b1b8a012dd41e35e651d945fbbda4881/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_functions.scss (line 96, column 11)
remote:     at options.error (/tmp/build_b1b8a012dd41e35e651d945fbbda4881/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:291:26)
remote:  @ ./src/assets/sass/app.scss 4:14-206
remote:  @ multi ./node_modules/ng2-dnd/bundles/style.css ./src/styles.scss ./src/assets/sass/app.scss ./src/assets/slick.css ./src/assets/slick-theme.css ./src/assets/calendar.css ./src/assets/notification.css
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 1
remote: npm ERR! remeli-web@0.0.2 heroku-postbuild: `ng build`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote: npm ERR! 
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the remeli-web@0.0.2 heroku-postbuild script.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote: 
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.uRy2g/_logs/2020-04-10T21_19_58_443Z-debug.log
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:        
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:        
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:        
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected
```

Does anyone faced some similar errors when trying to deploy to heroku?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I couldn’t find the problem with the lib dependencies, so I had to deploy my application as static html, after building it locally.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an issue with a typescript version in your project and what version on Heroku they are using.

If it looks like the difference in the typescript version wont make any issue, you can try running:

`ng set warnings.typescriptMismatch=false`

Answer (score 0):

It appears the typescript version is not compatible since its building production build.

`@angular/compiler-cli@5.2.11 requires typescript@'>=2.4.2 <2.5.0' but 2.9.2 was found instead.`

You might want to try moving your `"typescript": "^2.4.2"` from `devDependencies` to `dependencies` section and give that a shot.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer Anthony.
I am still receiving errors


`
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"ident":"postcss","sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false,"precision":8,"includePaths":[]}!./src/assets/sass/app.scss
remote: Module build failed: 
remote:   @return mix($color-base, $color, $level * $theme-color-interval);
`

Comment: Hard to tell from that shortened error message also how your webpack config is setup could be also causing this error combined with your dependencies.